# Django Multi-Tenancy

Tags: python, django, multi-tenant

How can i create a tenant_superuser in the schema which is not public?

```
raise SchemaError(tenants.tenant_users.tenants.models.SchemaError:Schema must be public for UserProfileManager user creation
```

I tried ./manage.py create_tenant_superuser --username=admin --schema=customer1
but got Schemaerror